# How to setup TrafficCounter in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I am writing an application where I need to track the sent/received bytes and bandwidth. I am using a library that itself uses Netty 5.0.

The only access I have to the Netty code is by extending this [class](https://github.com/Steveice10/PacketLib/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spacehq/packetlib/tcp/TcpClientSession.java) of the library I am using.

How do I create and setup a TrafficCounter in this class? I couldn't find any examples of how to do it on the web (at least not in Netty 5.0). I have multiple threads using Netty so I need the traffic per channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look to this PR which still contain a full example on how to use TrafficCounter (in fact TrafficShapingHandler):

https://github.com/fredericBregier/netty/tree/8f704e6020de364b031a77e1ee403d3ae4d8e10d/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/discard

And in particular for [DiscardServer](https://github.com/fredericBregier/netty/blob/8f704e6020de364b031a77e1ee403d3ae4d8e10d/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/discard/DiscardServer.java) which contains both Global and Channel Traffic Shaping, where the last one (ChannelTrafficShaping) is the one you're looking for.

So what you could have is the following:

```
        bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                getPacketProtocol().newClientSession(client, TcpClientSession.this);

                channel.config().setOption(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 0x18);
                channel.config().setOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, false);

                ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

                refreshReadTimeoutHandler(channel);
                refreshWriteTimeoutHandler(channel);

                pipeline.addLast("encryption", new TcpPacketEncryptor(TcpClientSession.this));
                pipeline.addLast("traffic", new ChannelTrafficShapingHandler(0, MAXCHANNELTHROUGHPUT, 1000)); // ADDED
                pipeline.addLast("sizer", new TcpPacketSizer(TcpClientSession.this));
                pipeline.addLast("codec", new TcpPacketCodec(TcpClientSession.this));
                pipeline.addLast("manager", TcpClientSession.this);
            }
        }).group(this.group).option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, getConnectTimeout() * 1000);
```

And look of course at the API: [Traffic](http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/package-summary.html) and in particular [ChannelTrafficShapingHandler](http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/ChannelTrafficShapingHandler.html)